# Returning new array with ascii values and numbers of previous array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm writing a function without the use of any JS built-in functions. This function accepts an array ['z','C',2,115,30] and then creates a new array with ascii values of chars in that first array plus the normal numbers that were there previously, so: [127, 67, 2, 115,30]. The problem I'm having is that I cannot properly get the numbers from the 1st array into the second array.

So far I can get the new array to [127,67,2,1,1,5,3,0]. So the chars ascii value is being inputted into the new array properly, but while iterating through the numbers it puts each digit of a number and then a comma into the array when i just want the whole number to be inputted instead of each digit.

```
function func(x){
    var str = '';
    var arr = [];
    for(var i=0; i<x.length;i++){
        str += x[i]
    }
    for(var j=0; j<str.length;j++){
        if(isNaN(str[j])){
            arr += str.charCodeAt(j) + ', ';
        }
        else if(!isNaN(str[j])){
            arr += str[j] + ', ';
        }
    } print(arr)

}

func(['z','C',2,115,30])
```

I expect output of [122, 67, 2, 115, 30], current output is [122, 67, 2, 1, 1, 5, 3, 0,]

Comment: The problem is the approach of turning the source array into a *string* in the first place. There's no reason to do that, and that's what's causing your problems. Iterate through the source array and determine what the type of each element is with `typeof` not `isNaN()` because `isNaN()` doesn't mean what one might think it means.

Comment: Also in general `if (something) else if (!something)` is pointless. If `something` is not true then `!something` **is** true, by definition.

Comment: @Pointy i cant get the ascii value of char unless its in a string using charCodeAt()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't combine into one string - instead, use a simple `for` loop:

```js
 

function func(x) {
  var arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
if (typeof x[i] == "string") arr[arr.length] = (x[i].charCodeAt(0);
else arr[arr.length] = x[i];
  }
  console.log(arr);
}

func(['z','C',2,115,30]);
```

Using array methods is much simpler though:

```js
 

function func(x) {
  var arr = x.map(e => typeof e == "string" ? e.charCodeAt(0) : e);
  console.log(arr);
}

func(['z','C',2,115,30]);
```

Comment: Can't use Js built in functions so .push and .map would give me 0 points in this case.

Comment: Fixed @Tiago - you can ignore the second one for your submission, it's just my take. The first one doesn't use any methods now.